# Runnable jar doesn't work from one machine to another

Tags: java

So when exporting the project as a runnable jar, the jar works fine on the current machine. 
Moving the jar to another machine, and it cannot find the main class:
Used cmd to get the error:

```
        Desktop>java -jar RunMe.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 500
        at pnl_user.readFile(pnl_user.java:667)
        at pnl_user.readTNS(pnl_user.java:432)
        at pnl_user.<init>(pnl_user.java:412)
        at main.<clinit>(main.java:9)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: This would normally mean you have a bug in your code.  Perhaps the data you read is different so you don't see the bug on the first machine.

Comment: correct! ...what a stupid thing to do from my part

Comment: Reading the exception carefully isn't as easy as it sounds. Stare at them for a few years and you start to get them ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a JAR file use `java -jar thejarfile.jar`.

`java runme` would try to run the class `runme` from the current classpath (which is probably not set up to point to your application).

Comment: I am trying to run the jar by double clicking (runnable jar). It works fine on one machine, not working on another.

Comment: @Ameoo: if you double-click it, how do you see that message? That should not open a command line window at all. What happens when you try the command I posted from `cmd`?

Comment: I used cmd to get the error, as from double clicking I get a dialog saying it cannot find the main class. I thought posting also the complete error would help (that's why I used cmd)

Comment: @Ameoo: **what** command did you execute to get the error above?

Comment: ok, forget about the error then, Why would a runnable jar work (by doubleclicking) on one machine, and wouldn't work on another?

Comment: @Ameoo: NO! Don't forget about the error! *Execute the command I gave you and look at the error message!* That will help you find out why double-clicking doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I guess that `pnl_user.readFile` is your code (or at least code you control and/or call): Find out why it tries to access an element of an array at index 500 and why that element doesn't exist.

Comment: ok...I saw that, but something is clearly fishy, since the jar is working perfectly on one computer, and has these problems on the other..

Comment: @Ameoo: [read this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)! "it works on my machine" doesn't tell you **anything** about the quality of the program. Chances are that your application depends on some specific state that's set up "correctly" on that one computer but not on others.

Answer (score 2):

Is this **runme** the jar name or main class in the jar?

To launch your app from a jar, you can do the below:

```
java -jar runme.jar
```